# How to align text in the Table in latex?

Tags: tables

I am writing a Table in Latex. I want `+-` to be center aligned in the `$N_{s}$` column. I wrote a code like the following but it is not aligned.

I have imported a package `\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}` but didn't help.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
   
    \begin{center}  
    %\label{tab:ul_data}
 \caption{\label{tab:ul_data} Summary of the reconstruction efficiency ($\epsilon$), signal yields ($N_{S}$), signal significance ($\mathcal{S}$) and upper limit (U.L.) on the signal yield ($N_{pl}^{UL}$) and branching fraction ($\mathcal{B}$) at 90\% confidence level for \textcolor{red}{each mode}.}

    %\resizebox{12cm}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
            \hline \hline
            Decay mode & $\epsilon$ (\%)& $N_S$ &\textcolor{red}{$\mathcal{S}$ ($\sigma$)}&$N_{pl}^{UL}$ & $\mathcal{B} \times 10^{-7}$ \\ [0.5ex] 
            \hline \hline
   \noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
            $D^{0} \rightarrow pe^{-}$ & 10.16 &\phantom{0}$-6.43 \pm 8.5$ & \textemdash& 16.2 & $ < 5.10 $  \\  [1ex]
            %\hline
            $\bar{D}^{0} \rightarrow pe^{-}$ & 10.19 & $-18.4 \pm 23$ & \textemdash& 22.0 & $< 6.94 $  \\  [1ex]
            %\hline
            $D^{0} \rightarrow \bar{p}e^{+}$ & \phantom{0}9.72 & \phantom{0}$-4.7 \pm 23$ & \textemdash& 21.6 & $< 7.10 $ \\  [1ex]
            %\hline
            $\bar{D}^{0} \rightarrow \bar{p}e^{+}$ & \phantom{0}9.62 & $7.1 \pm 9.0$ & 0.60& 23.0 & $< 7.64 $  \\  [1ex]
            %\hline
            $D^{0} \rightarrow p\mu^{-}$ & 10.75 & $11.0 \pm 23$ & 0.95& 17.1 & $<5.06$  \\  [1ex] 
            %\hline
            $\bar{D}^{0} \rightarrow p\mu^{-}$ & 10.71 &$-10.8 \pm 27$ & \textemdash& 20.5 & $<6.12 $  \\ [1ex] 
            %\hline
            $D^{0} \rightarrow \bar{p}\mu^{+}$ & 10.52 &\phantom{0}$-4.5 \pm 14$ & \textemdash& 21.0 & $<6.32$ \\ [1ex] 
            %\hline
            $\bar{D}^{0} \rightarrow \bar{p}\mu^{+}$ & 10.45 & \phantom{4}$16.7 \pm 8.8$ & 1.56& 21.4 & $<6.55$  \\ [1ex]  
            \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}
    
       \end{center}
    \end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `siunitx` package. This will not only allow you to align the `+-` signs, but you can also stop to manually fiddle with the alignment of the numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{uncertainty-mode = separate}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
 \caption{Summary of the reconstruction efficiency ($\epsilon$), signal yields ($N_{S}$), signal significance ($\mathcal{S}$) and upper limit (U.L.) on the signal yield ($N_{pl}^{UL}$) and branching fraction ($\mathcal{B}$) at 90\% confidence level for \textcolor{red}{each mode}.}
 \label{tab:ul_data} 
        \begin{tabular}{c S[table-format=2.2] S[table-format=-2.2+-2.2] S[table-format=1.2] S[table-format=2.1] S[table-format=<1.2]}
            \hline \hline
            {{Decay mode}} & {{$\epsilon$ (\%)}}& {{$N_S$}} &
            {{\textcolor{red}{$\mathcal{S}$($\sigma$)}}}
            &{{$N_{pl}^{UL}$}} & {{$\mathcal{B} \times 10^{-7}$}} \\ [0.5ex] 
            \hline \hline
            $D^{0} \rightarrow pe^{-}$ & 10.16 & -6.43 \pm 8.5 & {{\textemdash}}& 16.2 & < 5.10   \\  [1ex]
            %\hline
            $\bar{D}^{0} \rightarrow pe^{-}$ & 10.19 & -18.4 \pm 23 & {{\textemdash}}& 22.0 & < 6.94   \\  [1ex]
            %\hline
            $D^{0} \rightarrow \bar{p}e^{+}$ & 9.72 & -4.7 \pm 23 & {{\textemdash}}& 21.6 & < 7.10  \\  [1ex]
            %\hline
            $\bar{D}^{0} \rightarrow \bar{p}e^{+}$ & 9.62 & 7.1 \pm 9.0 & 0.60& 23.0 & < 7.64   \\  [1ex]
            %\hline
            $D^{0} \rightarrow p\mu^{-}$ & 10.75 & 11.0 \pm 23 & 0.95& 17.1 & <5.06  \\  [1ex] 
            %\hline
            $\bar{D}^{0} \rightarrow p\mu^{-}$ & 10.71 &-10.8 \pm 27 & {{\textemdash}}& 20.5 & <6.12   \\ [1ex] 
            %\hline
            $D^{0} \rightarrow \bar{p}\mu^{+}$ & 10.52 &-4.5 \pm 14 & {{\textemdash}}& 21.0 & <6.32 \\ [1ex] 
            %\hline
            $\bar{D}^{0} \rightarrow \bar{p}\mu^{+}$ & 10.45 & 16.7 \pm 8.8 & 1.56& 21.4 & <6.55  \\ [1ex]  
            \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did work. But one query: Why is the first number in the N_{s} column -6.43 \pm 8.50 instead of just -6.43 \pm 8.5? I mean one additional zero is appearing, why?.

Comment: The zero is appearing, because -6.43 has two digits after the decimal separator. You might want to check your significant figures

Comment: okay. I see. Thanks.

Comment: @SouvikMaity, because otherwise table will not compile.  Cause for this is data in your table: tolerances at some variables are much bigger than variable values. This id quite unusual (not expected) , actually wrong way, for writing such data as tolerance.  You should reconsider interpretation of your data, probably gives mean, min, max of `N_S`. BTW, your problem is not duplicate to to question given in closing note.

Comment: Could you please suggest to me how to create a space after the < symbol? Because if I gave the $<$ symbol and it does not compile. Thanks.

Comment: @SouvikMaity If you have a new question, please ask a new question