# How to create a thinspace?

Tags: tables, math-mode, siunitx

I have made a table (please see the attached code, obtained largely from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688391/5001)) in latex but I am not being able to create a thinspace after the "<" symbol.

If I put the dollar ($$) symbol or use \hspace{} then the code is not compiling. Could you please suggest to me how to resolve this issue?

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
 \caption{\textcolor{red}{Reconstruction efficiency ($\epsilon$), signal yield ($N_{S}$), signal significance ($\mathcal{S}$), upper limit on the signal yield ($N_{p\ell}^{UL}$) and branching fraction ($\mathcal{B}$) at 90\% confidence level for each mode}.}
 \label{tab:ul_data} 
        \begin{tabular}{c S[table-format=2.2] S[table-format=-2.2+-2.2] S[table-format=1.2] S[table-format=2.1] S[table-format=<1.2]}
            \hline \hline
            {{Decay mode}} & {{$\epsilon$ (\%)}}& {{$N_S$}} &
            {{$\mathcal{S}$($\sigma$)}}
            &{{$N_{p\ell}^{UL}$}} & {{$\mathcal{B} \times 10^{-7}$}} \\ [0.5ex] 
            \hline \hline
            $D^{0} \rightarrow pe^{-}$ & 10.16 & -6.4 \pm 8.5& {-} & 16.2 & < 5.1   \\  [1ex]
            %\hline
            $\bar{D}^{0} \rightarrow pe^{-}$ & 10.19 & -18.4 \pm 23 & {-} & 22.0 & < 6.9   \\  [1ex]
            %\hline
            $D^{0} \rightarrow \bar{p}e^{+}$ & 9.72 & -4.7 \pm 23 & {-} & 21.6 & < 7.1  \\  [1ex]
            %\hline
            $\bar{D}^{0} \rightarrow \bar{p}e^{+}$ & 9.62 & 7.1 \pm 9.0 & 0.60 & 23.0 & < 7.6   \\  [1ex]
            %\hline
            $D^{0} \rightarrow p\mu^{-}$ & 10.75 & 11.0 \pm 23 & 0.95 & 17.1 & <5.1  \\  [1ex] 
            %\hline
            $\bar{D}^{0} \rightarrow p\mu^{-}$ & 10.71 &-10.8 \pm 27 & {-} & 20.5 & <6.1   \\ [1ex] 
            %\hline
            $D^{0} \rightarrow \bar{p}\mu^{+}$ & 10.52 &-4.5 \pm 14 & {-} & 21.0 & <6.3 \\ [1ex] 
            %\hline
            $\bar{D}^{0} \rightarrow \bar{p}\mu^{+}$ & 10.45 & 16.7 \pm 8.8 & 1.56 & 21.4 & <6.5  \\ [1ex]  
            \hline \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: I don't see a way to customize the space between comparator and value in the manual. You could use `<2.2` though.

Comment: @Souvik Answers on this site are licensed under  CC BY-SA 4.0. If you reuse the code you got from a previous post, you should add a link back to were you got the code from. Please also don't post code fragements. You got a compilable minimal working example as answer, the least you could do is also provide one in your question.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - Done. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change the column type of the final column to `c` and insert `{}` (an "empty math atom") before each instance of `<` in that column.

I would also change the table type from `tabular` to `array` since most of the material is math-y. And I'd employ the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline\hline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Reconstruction efficiency ($\epsilon$), signal yield ($N_{S}$), signal significance ($\mathcal{S}$), upper limit on the signal yield ($N_{p\ell}^{UL}$), and branching fraction ($\mathcal{B}$) at 90\% confidence level for each decay mode.}
\label{tab:ul_data} 
\[
\begin{array}{@{} l T{2.2} T{-2.1+-3.0} T{1.2} T{2.1} c @{}}
\toprule
\mbox{Decay mode} & {\epsilon\ (\%)} & {N_S} 
& {\mathcal{S}(\sigma)} & {N_{p\ell}^{\mathrm{UL}}} 
& {\mathcal{B} {\times} 10^{-7}} \\  
\midrule
   D^{0} \to pe^{-}           & 10.16 & -6.4 \pm  8.5& {\text{--}} & 16.2 & {}< 5.1  \\  
   \bar{D}^{0} \to pe^{-}     & 10.19 &-18.4 \pm 23  & {\text{--}} & 22.0 & {}< 6.9  \\ 
\addlinespace
   D^{0} \to \bar{p}e^{+}     &  9.72 & -4.7 \pm 23  & {\text{--}} & 21.6 & {}< 7.1  \\  
   \bar{D}^{0}\to\bar{p}e^{+} &  9.62 &  7.1 \pm  9.0& 0.60        & 23.0 & {}< 7.6  \\  
\addlinespace
   D^{0} \to p\mu^{-}         & 10.75 & 11.0 \pm 23  & 0.95        & 17.1 & {}< 5.1  \\   
   \bar{D}^{0} \to p\mu^{-}   & 10.71 &-10.8 \pm 27  & {\text{--}} & 20.5 & {}< 6.1  \\  
\addlinespace
   D^{0} \to \bar{p}\mu^{+}   & 10.52 & -4.5 \pm 14  & {\text{--}} & 21.0 & {}< 6.3  \\  
   \bar{D}^0\to\bar{p}\mu^{+} & 10.45 & 16.7 \pm 8.8 & 1.56        & 21.4 & {}< 6.5  \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}
\]
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. My Table is getting created in a little bit of right aligned way. I want to move in the left side more.

Comment: @SouvikMaity - I'm afraid your comment is not very informative. The code shown above, which is adapted from the code you provided, produces a table that *is* centered. If the table in your document isn't centered, then its contents must deviate in some particulars from the one generated in my answer. Hence, please provide more information. If you feel that you'll to provide a lot more information in order to do justice to the issue, do consider creating a new query.